# Prevent cropping of background watermark

Tags: wpf

I am using the following technique to implement a watermark (I'm doing this from code in an attached property, but the following XAML demonstrates the issue):

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="txb">
            <TextBox.Background>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <Border Background="White">
                            <TextBlock Text="Hint text" Foreground="DarkGray" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, ElementName=txb}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </TextBox.Background>
        </TextBox>
        <Label Content="Label text here" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

However, within a `DockPanel`, the width of the first `TextBox` shrinks to a mininum, hiding the watermark.

How can I force WPF to take the width of the background into account when calculating the dimensions of the `TextBox`?

I imagine I can calculate the expected width of the text in the watermark and set the `MinWidth` of the control appropriately. However, I would prefer something simpler -- some property setting, or a databinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to make the `TextBox` automatically consider its background brush when measuring its desired size.  You could, however, explicitly bind its `MinWidth` to the width of the watermark:

```
<TextBox MinWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                            Path=Background.Visual.ActualWidth}"
         ...>
```

To force the some extra padding around the watermark, set the `Padding` on the `Border` within `VisualBrush.Visual`.

Note that this is a rather fragile binding that could lead to runtime exceptions if the background ever gets changed.  You might want to rework it.

Comment: Why is this fragile? Because a control might not have a `VisualBrush` as a background? But in the attached property that I am writing, I have set the background to a `VisualBrush`, so this is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Name="txb">
      .....
    <Label Content="Label text here" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This doesn't help me, as the attached property is set on the `TextBox` without any knowledge of the surrounding controls.